# How to autoplay on page load in loops using HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I found a lot of help on SO for autoplay, looping and onload play. But, there seems to be no answers to answer all of these together.

I tried 2 solutions:
**Solution#1** - HTML

```
<audio src="" id="music" loop muted></audio>
```

Solution#1 - JS

```
window.addEventListerner('load',()=>{
document.querySelector('#music').src = music.data[rand].preview //I am setting this to a .mp3 file
document.getElementById("music").play()
document.getElementById('music').muted = false
}
```

This solution requires the user to interact with the DOM before the mp3 is played

Now, **solution #2** was using iframes

```
<iframe loop="true" src="" allow="autoplay" id="music" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

solution#2 JS looks like:

```
window.addEventListerner('load',()=>{
document.querySelector('#music').src = music.data[rand].preview //I am setting this to a .mp3 file
}
```

This solution autoplays the .mp3 file, but, it does not loop.

Can somebody provide a solution which autoplays on load and also loops. I am working with .mp3 only. No videos. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you can only play non muted with user interaction? Doesn't matter if it's a video or mp3 or whatever.

Comment: I assume you are asking about the order. The order of those 2 statements actually does not matter for my use-case.

Comment: What I meant was, I don't think browsers allow you to autoplay a non muted mp3 file on loop. Because stuff like that annoys the visitor. You can implement a "play" button which then triggers the background-music on autoplay. Nothing you can do about this behaviour I'm afraid.

Comment: solution#1 allows me to autoplay on load. Now, I just need it to loop.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution: Use the video tag and play it as an mp3. Its kinda hacky

```
<video type="audio/mpeg" src="" allow="autoplay" id="music" style="display:none" loop autoplay></video>
```

In the JS file do

```
Inside any of your event listener
document.querySelector('#music').play()
```

This will autoplay on page load and also keep looping.