# Autoplay a mp3 file with Apps Script in Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, audio, autoplay

I have a Google Sheet with URLs of my audio Files from my own Google Drive Folder. I realised a Script from *labnol.org* (**thanks to @Amit Agarwal**) to Open a Mini Player in an iframe.

Is it possible to **autoplay** the file, if the mini Player is opend?

The Apps script is from Here: https://www.labnol.org/play-mp3-google-sheets-220504:

```
const openAudioPlayer = () => {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  const html = `<iframe src="${cell}" width="480" height="180" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`;
  const dialog = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('Play').setWidth(500).setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(dialog, 'Play Audio');
};
```

Comment: To get the audio player running requires some type of user input.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62720482/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60944078/1595451

Answer (score 2):

Use `autoplay` attribute of [`audio` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio):

```
/**
 * Plays audio from src specified in active cell
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/73228860/
 */
(()=>SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
      HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<audio src="${
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue()
      }" autoplay>`).setWidth(1).setHeight(1)
     ,"")
)()
```