# function that auto play sound when you fill all the checking box (in 1 row or column) in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvNR6.png)

I try to find on Google but didn't get any results. I'm a student don't know what to write to enoungh 220 character. Allow me to use dot.
......................................................

Comment: You need AppScript. Search on google please.

Comment: Why not start with playing an audio file from Google sheets? (worry about the checkboxes once you have this first step under control)? Related question: [Autoplay a mp3 file with Apps Script in Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73228296/1330560)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autoplay a mp3 file with Apps Script in Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73228296/autoplay-a-mp3-file-with-apps-script-in-google-sheets)